# Create and download zip file using CodeIgniter 4

Tags: codeigniter-4

Create and download zip file using CodeIgniter 4

I want to create a zip of images and download it.Please give any suggestion regarding my problem.my question is simple i want create create file zip file and download it.zip file contain images.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller create a new function:

```
public function download_zip() {

    // collect files you want to include in your zip file
    $filesList = [
        'imagesfolder/image1.jpg',
        'imagesfolder/image2.jpg',
        'imagesfolder/image3.jpg',
    ];

    $zip = new \ZipArchive();
    $zipFileName = 'images.zip';
    $zipFilePath = WRITEPATH . 'zips/' . $zipFileName; // Change the path as needed, dont forget to create a directory if it is not already there


    if ($zip->open($zipFilePath, \ZipArchive::CREATE | \ZipArchive::OVERWRITE)) {
        // Add files to the zip archive
        foreach ($filesList as $filePath) {
            if (file_exists($filePath)) {
                $zip->addFile($filePath, basename($filePath));
            }
        }

        $zip->close();

        // Send the zip file to the user
        return $this->response->download($zipFilePath, null)->setFileName(basename($zipFilePath));
    } else {
        return $this->response->setStatusCode(500)->setBody('Failed to create the zip file.');
    }

}
```

You didn't provide much information about your setup/environment, but
remember, that **all your zip files you created are stored on your server and can take up space during a longer period of time**. Be sure to delete them if you don't need them any more.

One approach could be to use a cron job, which deletes the zips folder once a day/week.

Or you could create a new function which serves the created zip and deletes it right after downloading.